# Apache2 Default Page appears even after VPS is stopped

Tags: linux, apache2, vps

I have a VPS on Hostinger.com. I configured a Virtual Host to direct to my website, but when I enter my IP address in a webbrowser, I see my html only sometimes... usually, I get the Apache2 Default Page. But if I sit in the browser and hit refresh repeatedly, sometimes I see my website, and sometimes I see the Default Page, and it doesn't seem to be correlated to anything I do.

When I stop the Apache2 service completely, for some reason, I still get the Apache2 Default Page. And if that isn't weird enough, I get it even after stopping my VPS entirely!

What on earth is going on?

Comment: Try modifying the default page just to verify that your request is served by your VPS instead of other server

Comment: I did that -- the default page I'm seeing doesn't have my modifications. I have no idea where it's coming from. The VPS is stopped.

Comment: Do you use the same IP to ssh into the VPS?

Comment: Yes. What's weird is that I can ping that IP. It's as if my IP address isn't unique.